# Get and Set sortation (Column and Ascending/Descending) of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I'm having a small problem. I need to save the sortation (by which Column and Ascending or Descending) and load it on the next start of the program.
Getting the currently selected Column is no problem i do this via

```
    private int GetSortColumn()
    {
        DataGridViewColumn sortColumn = this.dataGridView.SortedColumn;
        if (sortColumn != null)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.sortingColumnSortMode = dataGridView.SortOrder;
            return sortColumn.Index;
        }
        else
            //error
            return -1;
    }
```

And save the data in my settings.
Setting this property is also no problem:

```
    private void SetSortColumn(int indexOfColumn)
    {
        if (indexOfColumn != null && indexOfColumn != -1)
        {
            this.dataGridView.Sort(this.dataGridView.Columns[indexOfColumn], ListSortDirection.Descending);
        }
    }
```

But I need to save and set the ascending or descending property also. How do I do this?
Is there a way to get a ListSortDirection with the dataGridView.SortedColumn? Or is there a better solution to set if the dataGridView is sorted in ascending or descending order?

Thanks and greetings!
reijin

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this still relevant, but this looks like an easier way to do it :)

```
if(gridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending)
{
     // you can ascending if you want
     gridView1.Sort(gridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
}
else
{
      // you can descending if you want
     gridView1.Sort(gridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex], ListSortDirection.Descending);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, I was able to fix my problem by simply adding a switch in my SetSortColumn:

```
    private void SetSortColumn(int indexOfColumn)
    {
        if (indexOfColumn != null && indexOfColumn != -1)
        {
            ListSortDirection listSort;
            switch (Properties.Settings.Default.sortingColumnSortMode)
            {
                case SortOrder.Ascending:
                    listSort = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                    break;

                case SortOrder.Descending:
                    listSort = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                    break;

                default:
                    listSort = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                    break;

            }

            this.dataGridView.Sort(this.dataGridView.Columns[indexOfColumn], listSort);
        }
    }
```

Maybe it will help others ;)

Comment: yes this works to set it - but it does not tell you the DataGridView Columns sort direction.  Did you find out how to get the Columns Sort Direction so that you can use it ?